# CSS Display block for image not showing up or link not working

Tags: css

I've been trying for days to get background image and link to show up on my website.  However, when I set the background-image display:none, the images disappear, but the links work.  If I set the background-image display:block, the images appear, but the links don't work.

This is the link to the page...if you scroll to the bottom there are 3 images that are blank.  It's actually there, but when I put display:block, it just is not visible:

*CSS*

```
background-image: url("bali-villas-mobile.jpg");
background-position: 50% center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
border-radius: 3px !important;
display: block;
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
max-width: 100%;
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="hc_m_content_a">
<a class="hc_m_content_a" style="font-size:16px; color:#222324;" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</div>
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: can you add your codes to jsfiddle?

Comment: Why you use div around the a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML:

```
<a class="hc_m_content_a" href="#" alt="Image or Page name"></a>
```

Add or change to your CSS:

```
background-size: cover;
width: 350px; /*or something*/
```

If this does not work something else goes wrong, i am on mobile so cant inspect your link.

Answer (score 0):

My test at Fiddle shows your code without any problem.

[@Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grupocamaleon/q9216j67/embedded/result/)

```css
.hc_m_content_a {
background-image: url("bali-villas-mobile.jpg");
background-position: 50% center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
border-radius: 3px !important;
display: block;
height: 200px;
margin-bottom: 1rem;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hc_m_content_a">
<a class="hc_m_content_a" style="font-size:16px; color:#222324;" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</div>
```